# InputMismatchException error with Java Scanner when using Eclipse on Mac but not on Win10

Tags: java, eclipse, macos-mojave

I'm getting a behaviour that I can't understand. The code works perfectly on Win10 but throws an InputMismatchException error on MacOS. It breaks when trying to call nextDouble() or nextInt().

The call is made from this method:

```
public void readVehicleData() 
{
    Frame frame = null;
    FileDialog fileBox = new FileDialog(frame, "Open", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fileBox.setDirectory(".");
    fileBox.setVisible(true);

    String fileName = fileBox.getDirectory()+fileBox.getFile(); 

    try
    {
        File dataFile = new File(fileName);  
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);

        while(scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            String lineOfText = scanner.nextLine().trim(); 

            if (!lineOfText.startsWith("//") && !lineOfText.isEmpty() && !lineOfText.startsWith("["))
            {
                Scanner strScanner = new Scanner(lineOfText).useDelimiter("\\s*[,\n]\\s*");

                Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle(); 

                if(strScanner.hasNext())
                {
                     vehicle.readData(strScanner);
                     vehicleList.add(vehicle);

                     strScanner.nextLine();
                }

                strScanner.close();  
            }                                
        }

        if(scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            scanner.nextLine();
        }   

        scanner.close();
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        System.err.println(ex.getCause());
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("File " + fileName + " not found"); 
        fileName = null;
    }
```

The error occurs when reading "vehicle.readData(strScanner)", which looks like this:

```
public void readData(Scanner strScanner) 
{
   group = strScanner.next();
   vehID = strScanner.next(); 
   regNo = strScanner.next();
   make = strScanner.next();    
   model = strScanner.next();    

   String strAirCon = strScanner.next();                          
   airCon = strAirCon.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") == true ? true : false; 

   // It throws an InputMismatchException error here 
   engineSize = strScanner.nextDouble();   

   fuelType = strScanner.next(); 
   gearbox = strScanner.next();
   transmission = strScanner.next();

   // It also throws an InputMismatchException error here 
   // if the previous variables are commented
   mileage = strScanner.nextInt();


   dateFirstRegistered = strScanner.next();
}
```

These are the errors I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
at vehicleproject.Vehicle.readData(Vehicle.java:121)
at vehicleproject.ReservationSystem.readVehicleData(ReservationSystem.java:65)
at vehicleproject.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

I've obviously done my research but can't find any solution for that. It works without any issue on Win10 but not on MacOS.

Has anyone experience the same type of error on MacOS?

This is an example of the data I need to read:

[Car data]

// data is Group, VehID, RegNo, Make, Model, AirCon or Climate Control, Engine Size (litres), Fuel type, Gearbox, Transmission, Mileage, Date first registered, Body type, Number of doors, Number of seats

AA, TF-63403, MJ09TFE, Fiat, Panda Active Eco, No,  1.1, Unleaded, five-speed manual, FWD, 13584, 29-07-2009, Hatchback, 5, 5
A, TF-61273, MJ09TFD, Fiat, Grande Punto Active, No, 1.4, Unleaded, five-speed manual, FWD, 14278, 12-05-2009, Hatchback, 3, 5

This is one of the classes:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Vehicle
{
    private String group, vehID, regNo, make;
    private String model, fuelType, gearbox, transmission, dateFirstRegistered;
    private boolean airCon;
    private double engineSize;
    private int mileage;


    public Vehicle()
    {
        group = null;
        vehID = null;
        regNo = null;
        make = null;
        model = null;
        airCon = false;
        engineSize = 0.0;
        fuelType = null;
        gearbox = null;
        transmission = null;
        mileage = 0;
        dateFirstRegistered = null;      
    }

    public String getGroup()
    {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(String newGroup)
    {
        group = newGroup;
    }

    public String getVehicleID()
    {
        return vehID;
    }

    public void setVehicleID(String newVehID)
    {
        vehID = newVehID;
    }

    public String getRegistrationNo()
    {
        return regNo;
    }

    public void setRegistrationNo(String newRegNo)
    {
        regNo = newRegNo;
    }

    public String getMake()
    {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String newMake)
    {
        make = newMake;
    }

    public String getModel()
    {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String newModel)
    {
        model = newModel;
    }

    public boolean getAirCon()
    {
        return airCon;
    }

    private String checkAirCon()
    {
        String output;              
        return output = getAirCon() == true ? "Yes" : "No";
    }

    public void printDetails()
    {
        System.out.println(make + " " + model + "  Group: " + group + "  Vehicle Id: " + vehID);
        System.out.println("Air conditioning / Climate control: " + checkAirCon());
        System.out.println("Engine Size: " + engineSize + "    Fuel: " + fuelType);
        System.out.println("Gearbox: " + gearbox + "  Transmission: " + transmission);
        System.out.println("Mileage: " + mileage + "  Date first registered: " + dateFirstRegistered);
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void readData(Scanner strScanner) 
    {
       group = strScanner.next();
       vehID = strScanner.next(); 
       regNo = strScanner.next();
       make = strScanner.next();    
       model = strScanner.next();    
       //System.out.println(model); 

       String strAirCon = strScanner.next();                          
       airCon = strAirCon.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") == true ? true : false; 

       engineSize = strScanner.nextDouble();
       //System.out.println(engineSize);    

       fuelType = strScanner.next(); 
       gearbox = strScanner.next();
       transmission = strScanner.next();

       mileage = strScanner.nextInt();
       //System.out.println(mileage); 

       dateFirstRegistered = strScanner.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try to change `.next()` methods to `nextLine()`?

Comment: That's not the source of the problem, I've tested it thoroughly. I need the nextLine() there. The error only occurs on MacOS, not on Win10. Very unusual.

Comment: Would you upload any demo data (file with data)?

Comment: I've pasted a sample of the file the program reads

Comment: For those data I'm receiving properly parsed Vehicle object. Tested on macOS 10.4.3. in IntelliJ 2018.3.

Comment: Would you add your `Vehicle` class?

Comment: That's definitely odd. I've even tested on NetBeans 8.2 and throws the same error. Sure I'll add the class.

Comment: Still cannot reproduce. Code works properly (using yours classes).